# react-dom and rollupjs: Cannot assign to read only property 'history' of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup to bundle my React app, and I'm currently getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'history' of object '[object Window]'(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:6115

which is in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDCyf.png) location.

My rollup config:

```
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import cjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import jsx from 'rollup-plugin-jsx';
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble';

export default {
    entry: 'app/main.js',
    format: 'cjs',
    plugins: [
        json(),
        postcss(),
        cjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/react/react.js': [ 'createElement', 'Component' ],
                'node_modules/react-dom/index.js': [ 'render' ]
            }
        }),
        resolve({ jsnext: true, main: true }),
        replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development') }),
        jsx({ factory: 'React.createElement' }),
        buble(),
    ],
    dest: 'public/bundle.js'
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I ran into this when updating an app to a newer version of ReactDOM as well. The current solution is to either use a different formatter for output, e.g. UMD, iife, or to revert to an older ReactDOM, such as `15.2.1`.

Comment: thanks! I'll refer to your comment if I go back to rollup. feel free to leave it as an answer and I can mark it then.